# winpdb is not recognising function inputs?

Tags: python, winpdb

This is my first post! :D

I am trying to learn how to use winpdb to debug some python code and have a problem. Consider the following python function, simple.py:

```
   def simple(a,b):

    c  = a + b

    return c
```

I am in windows and using the command line in the directory where I have stored this function I attempt to run winpdb with the following command:

```
winpdb simple.py 2 1
```

Is this the correct way to debug the function simple.py with `a = 2` and `b = 1`? As when I execute the above in the command line winpdb launches but with `a` and `b` undefined, for example (taken from the winpdb console when the above is entered into the cmd window):

```
> eval a
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>, name 'a' is not defined
```

I am sorry to have to ask such a basic question, but I can not seem to find any solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

The presented source file defines a function but it never calls the function and doesn't execute any code at all. Code in exactly that form can't be trivially debugged.
Typically a sample call to function is added to the end of file, like

```
def simple(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
simple(1, 2)
```

Than you can start winpdb like

```
winpdb simple.py
```

place breakpoint in a function by clicking on margin of `c = a + b` line and press the Go button.

After that the program would stop in a state where you can use `eval a` and even `eval simple(5, 6)`